# How to do exponentiation e when 'e' is decimal for very large numbers of e?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, exponential

Say,

base = 2 and e = 20000.5671

How to perform (base power e) for above example in java.

Clearly Math.pow(base, e) is not the way to go as it print's "Infinity"

and BigDecimal accepts 'e' of type int only.

Any other way to achieve this? Expecting more of a JDK library rather than 3p.

Comment: Do you have an idea about how big 2*20000 is? Don't think that modern computers could even store such a number.

Comment: Still why BigDecimal.pow accepts int and Math.pow accepts double?

Comment: @Andrea it's this big that SO comment overflow notification says 5647 chars extra :)

Comment: @Andrea: It's quickly calculable and easily fits on a single computer screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using [exponent product rule](http://www.math.com/school/subject2/lessons/S2U2L2DP.html).

*a<sup>b+c</sup> = a<sup>b</sup> * a<sup>c</sup>*

so you can raise 2 to the power of 20000 using the BigDecimal function then multiply by 2 raised to the power 0.5671

#### Note :-

*This approach will produce an answer that will only be correct to the precision of the least of its parts. The `Math.pow` function returns a double, and so is only accurate to around 15 significant figures.*

Comment: No! it's not possible as `^` only applies to ints

Comment: @VinayPrajapati  is expressing power, not verbatim code. he  knows a function that can do this

Comment: Seems to work, although it's difficult to verify for those large numbers: `BigDecimal.valueOf(b).pow((int) e).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(b, e % 1)));`

Comment: can someone explain `^` as bitwise OR. I tried ~aaron's solutions.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati That is not Java. Aaron explains the math, and is using math notation, assuming that OP will be able to translate that to proper Java.

Comment: @tobias_k You can give the output a sanity check using similar maths tricks. 2^20000.5671 is the same as 10^(log_10(2)*20000.5671). log_10(2)*20000.5671 = 6020.770627. Then using the trick in the answer  10^0.770627 is around 5.89594. So the answer should be in the region of 5.89594E+6020. p.s. thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a mathematical workaround:

```java
BigDecimal.valueOf(2).pow(20000).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(2, .5671)))
```

Comment: Yeah! removed for now.